# Airflow KubernetesPodOperator : how to access secret passed to Pod?

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetespodoperator

I am trying to pass secret variables to my `KubernetesPodOperator` in airflow

Here is what I have done :

1. Create a `secret.yaml` file that looks like the following

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  SECRET_1: blabla 
  SECRET_2: blibli
```

2. Apply the secret :

```sh
kubectl apply -f ./secret.yaml
```

3. Retrieve the secret from my DAG file :

```py
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.secret import Secret
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.models import DAG

SECRET_1 = Secret(
   deploy_type="env", deploy_target="SECRET_1", secret="ai-controller-object-storage", key="SECRET_1"
)
SECRET_2 = Secret(
   deploy_type="env", deploy_target="SECRET_2", secret="ai-controller-object-storage", key="SECRET_2"
)

with DAG(...) as dag:
   KubernetesPodOperator(
           task_id=..,
           trigger_rule="all_success",
           namespace="default",
           image=IMAGE,
           startup_timeout_seconds=600,
           secrets=[
               SECRET_1,
               SECRET_2], ...)
```

So now as I understand, I should access `SECRET_1` as environnement variable in my container from `KubernetesPodOperator`

However my first task from a python script (with `os.environ["SECRET_1"]`) returns an error that indicates that this environment variable does not exist :

```
KeyError: 'SECRET_1'
```

How can I access this variable from my python script then ?

Comment: Apparently this was fixed with airflow 2

Comment: What is the pip package required to import `from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.secret import Secret`?
I am getting a error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.contrib.kubernetes'`

Comment: you need to install airflow with the kubernetes extension : ```pip install airflow[kubernetes]```

Comment: It is already installed, yet I'm unable to import the Secret

Comment: Oh right, this post was made with airflow 1.xx, if you are using airflow 2.0 and above the import should be : ```from airflow.kubernetes.secret import Secret```

cf : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/example_dags/example_kubernetes.html

Comment: Has anyone come up with a solution for this in Airflow 1.xx?